# csv file to 2d list, then splitting onto list of 2d lists

Tags: python, list, numpy, csv, append

I read a csv file into a 2d list:

```
aData = loadtxt(sPath, delimiter=',')
```

that i could directly split into two 2d list:

```
X = aData[:,10:]    # neural net output
Y = aData[:,2:10]   # neural net input
```

But before that i want to spread `aData` onto 6 different 2d-lists

```
aDataW = [  [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]]  ]  # no idea if this is correct :-(
```

and then something like

```
for i in range(len(aData)):
    iW = 4  # my logic..
    aDataW[iW].append(aData[i])
```

But when then I get the error

```
aDataN = aDataW[4]
X = aDataM[:,10:]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

Comment: Python lists *don't have dimensions*. `aData` is a list, presumably, you'd hoped to manipulate it like a `numpy.ndarray` what is `loadtxt`?

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html

Comment: According to the error, `aDataM` is a list.  `aDataM[:,10:]` is valid style of indexing for an array, as when you split `aData`.  Do you understand that Python `list` is different from `numpy.ndarray`?

Comment: There isn't such a thing as 2d list.  A list may contain lists, but each has to be indexed separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to convert the list of lists back to a 2d array with `np.asarray()`
Working example:

```
import numpy as np

hFile = open("test.csv", "w")
hFile.write('1,1,3,4\n1,0,1,2\n0,1,1,7')
hFile.close()

aData = np.loadtxt('test.csv', delimiter=',')
print '\naData:'
print aData

aaData = [  [], [], []  ]    # 'split' aData onto 3 2d-arrays
print '\naaData:'
print aaData

for i in range(len(aData)):
    aPred = aData[i,0:2]
    iW = int(aPred[0]+aPred[0])
    aaData[iW].append(aData[i])

for i in range(len(aaData)):
    aaData[i] = np.asarray(aaData[i])

print '\naaData[2]:'
print aaData[2]

X = aaData[2][:,2:]     # neural net input
Y = aaData[2][:,0:2]    # neural net output

print '\nX:'
print X
```

output:

```
aData:
[[1. 1. 3. 4.]
 [1. 0. 1. 2.]
 [0. 1. 1. 7.]]

aaData:
[[], [], []]

aaData[2]:
[[1. 1. 3. 4.]
 [1. 0. 1. 2.]]

X:
[[3. 4.]
 [1. 2.]]
```

**Silly Python**  :  *'Fancy operators for complex data are proof that you have not understood OOP at all and still live in the 20th century.'* (Robo Durden)